# Converting the power series from sigma notation to a function?

Tags: calculus

The sigma notation for the power series is equivalent to the following function:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

However, given the sigma notation above, 
how would one arrive at it's equivalent function?

Comment: For all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $\sum_{n=0}^N x^n=\frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}$, if $x\in]-1,1[$, then $\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow +\infty}x^N=0$ so that $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $|x|<1$, else the series does not converge. Let $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k$. Then
$$
(1-x)S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k - \sum_{k=0}^n x^{k+1} = 1 -x^{n+1}.
$$
Dividing by $1-x$ yields
$$
S_n = \frac{1 -x^{n+1}}{1-x}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \frac1{1-x}.
$$